# Emacs goto-line in terminator not working

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, terminator

I am using terminator in ubuntu instead of the default terminal, and run emacs -nw on it. Here the M-g M-g command for going to a line is not responding and working (in the default ubuntu terminal it works fine!).
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure if you figured this out, but after much searching, I have found that terminator was capturing `M-g` and not passing it to emacs. Go to keybindings in terminator and remap that shortcut to something else.

Comment: there is no shortcut in the keybindings list

Comment: I'm running Emacs 24.4.1 in terminator 0.97 on Debian Jessie derived Bunsen Linux. M-g M-g is giving me goto-line. My meta key is the escape key.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click anywhere in the Terminator window and select `Preferences`, then `Keybindings`. You should see a window like this:

[image: Terminator Preferences window]

Double-click the text `Alt+G` (at the end of the second line, assigned to *broadcast_group* by default) and press the backspace key. The text should then read "Disabled". Now run Emacs in the current terminal. Entering the `M-g g` shortcut should prompt for a line to jump to.